# Flutter Firestore Query Listen - Can't refer to variable from Listen

Tags: search, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I have a Query to find the documentID for a specified barcode as such:

```
Future findBarcode() async {
  String searchBarcode = await BarcodeScanner.scan();

Firestore.instance.collection('${newUser.userLocation}').where('barcode', isEqualTo: '${searchBarcode}').snapshots().listen(
(data) { 
  String idOfBarcodeValue = data.documents[0].documentID;
  print(idOfBarcodeValue);
     }
  );  
}
```

However, I want to refer to the idOfBarcodeValue outside of the function. I'm trying to find a way to pass that to another function to pass into a SimpleDialog.

Presently, nothing outside of the function recognizes it. It does work, the print verifies.

Here is the scan function that is also being performed:

```
Future scan() async {
   try {
    String barcode = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
    setState(() => this.barcode = barcode);
        } on PlatformException catch (e) {
          if (e.code == BarcodeScanner.CameraAccessDenied) {
            setState(() {
              this.barcode = 'The user did not grant the camera permission!';
            });
          } else {
            setState(() => this.barcode = 'Unknown error: $e');
          }
        } on FormatException{
          setState(() => this.barcode = 'null (User returned using the "back"-button before scanning anything. Result)');
        } catch (e) {
          setState(() => this.barcode = 'Unknown error: $e');
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`snapshots()` returns a `Stream<Query>`. In the same way that you would `await` a function returning `Future`, you can `await for` all of the values (could be zero, one or more) that a `Stream` produces, for example:

```
Future findBarcode() async {
  String searchBarcode = await BarcodeScanner.scan();

  String idOfBarcodeValue;
  Stream<Query> stream = Firestore.instance
      .collection('${newUser.userLocation}')
      .where('barcode', isEqualTo: '${searchBarcode}')
      .snapshots();
  await for (Query q in stream) {
    idOfBarcodeValue = q.documents[0].documentID;
  }

  print(idOfBarcodeValue);
  // if the stream had no results, this will be null
  // if the stream has one or more results, this will be the last result
  return idOfBarcodeValue;
}
```

Comment: That isn't working for me. The print(idOfBarcodeValue) still doesn't even get called. Same problem as the initial method. If, I move the print statement inside of the await method, it works. Wont work for what I need though.

Comment: If you add a print inside the await for loop what do you see? If you add a `print('here');` after the loop when do you see it?

Comment: If I print inside of the loop, I see it. If I print outside of the loop - nothing happens. Seems to break before then. Can't figure out why.

Comment: What I am ultimately trying to do is to pass the idOfBarcodeValue to a Navigator.push() and to a new view as a value.

Comment: do you ever see the `print('here');` after the loop? Or, if you pass `context` into `findBarcode` can you call `Navigator.push` inside the `await for` loop?

Comment: No. print('here'); did not show after the loop. I will try passing context into findBarcode. Didn't think of/realize that. Tried without and there was a context error. (I'm self-taught/learning so please excuse any amateur mistakes)

Comment: Passing in context resolved it. Richard Heap, is there a way to put that for statement inside an if statement? So I can perform an action if a match is not found?

Comment: Interesting question... It's not clear to me why that firestore `.where().snapshots()` stream doesn't complete after all matching results are returned, which should allow it to drop out of the `await for` loop. My suggestion would be to ask precisely that question with as small an example as possible and hopefully a firestore expert will suggest a different query. After all, as you mention, if it doesn't complete, how do you know there were zero results?

Answer (score 0):

I think i should revision the code from **Richard Heap**, This is my latest code about barcode scan in 7 March 2020, you can use it for barcode scan if you want to get where value from barcode

```
String barcode = "";
Future scan() async {
try {
  barcode = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
  setState(() => this.barcode = barcode);

  String idOfBarcodeValue;
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> stream = dbReference
      .collection('userLocation')
      .where('qrCodeNumber', isEqualTo: barcode)
      .snapshots();
  await for (QuerySnapshot q in stream) {
    idOfBarcodeValue = q.documents[0].documentID;
    print(idOfBarcodeValue);
  }

} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == BarcodeScanner.CameraAccessDenied) {
    setState(() {
      this.barcode = 'The user did not grant the camera permission!';
    });
  } else {
    setState(() => this.barcode = 'Unknown error: $e');
  }
} on FormatException {
  setState(() =>
      this.barcode = 'User after click "back"-button before result');
} catch (e) {
  setState(() => this.barcode = 'Unknown error: $e');
}
```